# Abstract alphabets by Kolmogorov??

Tags: formal-languages

As a linguist I sometimes have a hard time trying to figure out the sense in which mathematical concepts are / might be used in my discipline. It is no wonder that we linguists are fascinated by the invention of the alphabet as a seminal milestone in Human History. However, mathematics plays around with the concept in a manner I would like to fully grasp. 
Thus, for instance, I find what I render a useful (and probably standard)  definition can be found in

Johannes A. Buchmann
Introduction to cryptography, New York, Springer, 2001. p. 73:

“To write texts, we need symbols from an alphabet. By an alphabet we mean a finite nonempty set $\Sigma$. The length of $\Sigma$ is the number of elements in $\Sigma$. The elements of $\Sigma$ are called symbols or letters.”

“Because alphabets are finite sets, their symbols can be identified with nonnegative integers. If an alphabet has length $m$, then its symbols are identified with the numbers in $\mathbb Ζ_m = \{0,1,\ldots, m-1\}$

Then he proceeds to elaborate on that in a fashion which will be too trivial for our audience here.

The fact is that, while reading some popular science book in Spanish about Kolmogorov, in the chapter about Kolmogorov complexity, after introducing all the typical concepts (entropy, mutual information and the like), they mentioned that Kolmogorov and his collaborators extended their ideas about finite alphabets (for a linguist the feature 'finite' seems substantial to the definition of alphabet) to what they called infinite alphabets. I have been searching on the web, in English, German and Spanish, but did not find any insightful or useful comment in this regard.
Could someone explain me what an infinite alphabet is and, specifically, how Kolmogorov complexity, epsylon-entropy and so on ought to be understood for infinite alphabets?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: An infinite alphabet is what it sounds like - an infinite set of symbols.

Comment: Well, but from my linguistically-biased mind anytime you talk about infinite or innumerable symbols your are no longer dealing with an alphabet, but rather mapping symbols which might originally be letters to integer numbers. Numbers do not enter in compositionality relationsthe (same)way as letters do as the generating matrix for words.

Comment: mathematics considers all sorts of infinite things. However, in more ordinary terms, the only reasonable way to get an infinite alphabet is to start with a finite alphabet and let, say, any finite sequence of letters be regarded as  a new letter. Valid, yes, but not clear how different, in human terms, this is from the original finite alphabet.

Comment: A very close mathematical construction is decimal notation, credited to Archimedes I think. In modern terms, we have the alphabet $0123456789$ and we get an infinite "alphabet" if we allow all finite strings (perhaps not beginning with $0$) because we get all positive integers. However, ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language has some remarks on the finiteness of alphabets.

Comment: @ Will Jagy. So sou are saying that the extension of the alphabet is always metalinguistically- (or metamathematically. if you want) grounded, that is, achieved by giving a constant name to a definite string of symbols? Something like saying, any pa sequence will be referred to (at the next level of analysis as delta, or the like? Still, I am not sure that recursivity maes it infinite strictly speaking, unless you start inventing new symbols on the fly.....Or am I wrong?

Comment: In which way did Kolmogorov and collaborators extend the concept of alphabet and related infinite alphabets to complexity?

Comment: Javier, I should not pretend to know what metalinguistically means. I am suggesting a reason that infinite alphabets need not be important to you at this stage of inquiry.

Comment: Part two, I should not pretend to know what Kolmogorov complexity is.  After looking at your profile, if I think of someone who could give a substantial answer, I will forward the web address for this question. I like it when research questions in other fields show up, a relief from the endless homework.

Comment: I have edited the question to call the alphabet $\Sigma$ instead of an undefined unicode character. $\Sigma$ is the conventional letter to use for alphabets in formal language theory -- but it is not an "epsilon", rather a "sigma". (I'm assuming you call it "epsylon" due to unfamiliarity with the Greek alphabet (!), though).

Comment: Sorry, It was just a lapse. Of course I know it is a sigma, and not an epsylon. Thanks a lot for editing it; I am still getting familiar with the forum. I hope i soon learn how to insert symbols, since copy and paste from word does nor seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess Shannon and Kolmogorov first started with defining the capacity or entropy of binary channels (i.e. messages over the alphabet {0,1} with some Bernoulli measure), but as always later on mathematics took over to generalize this as much as possible while keeping the important properties and results about entropy.

Nowadays Kolmogorov(-Sinai) entropy is a very important tool in dynamical systems and ergodic theory and the Gauss map is just one example of a dynamical system which has many applications also to number theory etc. The thing is that it should be treated using a countable partition (just because of the map having a countable number of surjective branches) and this can be done by the generalized theory of Kolmogorov entropy treating countable alphabets.

Comment: I guess the value of the entropy varies depending on whether the channel is memoryless or not, right?

Comment: By the way, it sound lie that countable partition could give rise to a version of the Banach-Tarski paradox, right?

Comment: If your channel has a Bernoulli measure the Kolmogorov entropy can be computed with the formula $h(\mu)=-sum_{A\in P}p(A)\log p(A)$ where $P$ is a generating partition (e.g. single letters of your alphabet). For channels where the measure is not just a product measure, e.g. one with a Markov measure (i.e. a Markov chain) the formula gets more complicated taking into account transition probabilities which correspond to the memory of the channel.

Comment: I don't see how countable partitions would give rise to a Banach-Tarski paradox. The measure is still a probability (i.e. finite and normalised) and the partition consists of measurable sets that only overlap in a null-set.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should be careful not to attach any deep importance to the word "alphabet" here. From a linguistic point of view, the essential (and once revolutionary) feature of an *alphabet* is as far as I know that its symbols denote *sounds* rather than discrete words or concepts. This angle is, of course, completely absent in the mathematical use of the word. We've simply co-opted the word "alphabet" to stand for whichever inventory of symbols the strings in our mathematical theory are put together from. If the mathematicians who first formulated the theory had spoken a language written with a different script, the same concept might well have ended up being called a "syllabary", "script" or something like that.

A *practical* alphabet with symbols that can be reliably and quickly distinguished from each other by a person or a machine can only have finitely many different symbols. (Turing quipped that Chinese "attempts to have a denumerable infinity of symbols", but I don't think he spoke much Chinese).

Thus, most of the theory of formal languages (and its neighboring areas of computability, complexity, automata theory, and so forth) assume *by default* that the alphabet is a finite set.

It turns out *after the fact* that some parts of the theory don't *use* the assumption that the alphabet is finite, so there are some -- but not all! -- of its theorems that are still true even if $\Sigma$ happens to be an infinite set. This subset of the theory can sometimes be technically useful in that we can reason about sequences of, say, numbers *as if* they were sequences of characters, as long as we take care to keep within the part of the theory that works for infinite alphabets. That doesn't mean that one is claiming that an arbitrary number is *actually* an indivisibly write-down-able symbol -- just that it can be a useful *analogy* and *intuition* to imagine that it is, for some purposes.

That's really all there is to it: A theory made to deal with finite sets as alphabets turns out to be partially useful when the set in question is infinite, and it is useful for those purposes to keep explicitly track of which parts of the theory still work then.

Now what does this have to do with **Kolmogorov complexity** in particular? To the best of my knowledge (and I'm a computer scientist with a fairly theoretical slant, so I *ought* to know) nothing at all. Kolmogorov complexity is one of those areas of the theory that *don't* keep working if we use a finite alphabet -- it depends *fundamentally* on the finiteness of the alphabet. Allowing an infinite alphabet there would either (depending on just how we slice it) collapse everything into having a uniformly small complexity measure, or consider almost everything to have *infinite* complexity, which isn't very interesting either.

(Note that Kolmogorov was quite a polymath; he worked on a lot of things that are not specifically connected to Kolmogorov complexity).

Comment: This is an excellent answer, Henning. Thanks a lot. By the way, my popular science text in Spanish says the following (I translate to the best of my knowledge): []

Comment: This is an excellent answer, Henning. Thanks a lot. By the way, my popular science text in Spanish says the following (I translate to the best of my knowledge)[THEY HAVE JUST TALKED ABOUT CONDITIONAL ENTROPY AND MUTUAL INFORMATION]: Kolmogorov, together with his collaborators devoted then himself to the task of elaborating a body of precise mathematical definitions in order to develop Shannon's ideas with the due mathematical rigour" [THEN THEY TALKED ABOUT A GENERALIZED OR EXTENDED TREATMENT]

Comment: They go on saying: "In these works not only binary signals were considered, or those taken from a finite alphabet but rather extended the results to the case of abstract alphabets, providing definitions for them and perfectly general results".

Comment: @JavierArias: Yes, it sounds reasonable that Shannon entropy can be formulated for a (countably) infinite alphabet with an appropriate probability distribution on it. But that is not quite the same setting as (what is usually known as) Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm. Sorry, then I got it wrong and confused some of the concepts. The question is then. How exactly does that extension of Shannon entropy work for an infinite alphabet? Any hint at it?

Comment: @JavierArias: That's not an area, I'm extremely familiar with, but the key result would be something like: For an alphabet $\Sigma$ and a probability measure $p$ on $\Sigma$, there is a coding such that a sequence of independently random symbols can be transmitted using _on average_ $$\sum_{a\in \Sigma} p(a)\log_2 \frac1{p(a)}$$ bits. This formula would work equally well with an infinite $\Sigma$, except the sum is now over an infinite set, and techniques from real analysis have to be brought in to sum it. There may be some additional conditions to make sure it converges.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm.   Thanks a lot for the illustration.

Comment: Does the question of finite vs infinite alphabets directly relate to the nature of the transmission channel and / or the discreteness or continuity of the variable to be transmitted? According to those 2 features we have 4 different possible scenarios (memoryless channel with discrete signal, channel with memory for a continuous signal and so on). Would the same formula for calculation of entropy apply in all cases?

Comment: @JavierArias: I don't remember the details of the theory well enough to answer that properly.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm. Ok, never mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kolmogorov information and entropy indeed works for countable partitions of the phase space, which can be thought of as a countable alphabet. (This is the only infinite cardinality to be considered for finite measures.)

One standard example is the Gauss map which has countably many branches in the interval $[0,1]$. Now code the intervals for every one of those branches by a symbol, then you naturally need countably many of them (usually one uses the natural numbers $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ as an alphabet in this case).

The question now is to find an invariant measure for this map (the Gauss measure) and then we can use Kolmogorov's formalism for countable alphabets (or partitions) to compute the entropy of the Gauss map with respect to this measure.

As a reference for the Gauss map look at: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/magic/lecture07.pdf
or the book by Brin Stuck on Dynamical Systems.

For the general framework take a look at the book by Petersen on Egodic Theory (pages 234-240) or the yet unpublished book by Einsiedler, Lindenstrauss and Ward: http://www.math.washington.edu/~solomyak/TEACH/582/11/EiLiWa_draft.pdf

Comment: As far as I know, Kolmogorov was interested in the complexity of strings in words, or of words in sentences. He even applied some of this concepts to the analysis of Pushkin's poetry. That is, letters of a given writing systems were the primitives he was playing around. He certainly used numbers for naming sequences of strings or the like, but I am not sue how to reconcile this with the Gauss maps you mention, or with the intinite cardinality within a given interval....Maybe I just do not understand mucho of maths and it is in fact ver easy, I just do not grasp it right now.